# Preventing CKEditor from adding <p> tags to content

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor for my HTML page. After loading the page I click on the div and make it editable. But the problem is that it automatically adds some p tags and some another tags.

Eg
before click

```
<div style="width:100%;" class="homeHead editor ">
<i>My content.</i>
</div>
```

but after click

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 100%; position: relative;" class="homeHead editor cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_53">
<p><em>Affordable. Simple.</em></p>
</div>
```

how can i maintain my previous HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is helpful to solve Your Problem

```
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
 {
   config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
 };
```

The  "config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR" will be Changed "p"  tag into "br" tag.

Answer (score 2):

Put "CKEDITOR.config.enterMode" and "config.allowedContent" inside your config.js file as follows -

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```